# Problema con bottom overflowed usando una columna en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

me gustaria que puedan ayudarme con este problema que tengo al usar una columna con su ultimo elemento abajo con expanded. bueno les comparto mi codigo:

Este esel build que aqui pienso que no es el problema que pero lo comparto por si acaso.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  blocGeneral = Provider.of(context);
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AYUDA"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call) , onPressed: () { }),
        ],
    ),
    body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
              _fondo(),
              _demasElementos(context)
          ],
    ),
   );
 }
```

en este pedazo de codigo es donde estoy utilizando mi columna:

```
   Widget _demasElementos(BuildContext contexto){
    return Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox( height: 10.0, ),
                  _contactaMe(contexto),
                  SizedBox( height: 10.0, ),
                  _textField(contexto),
                  SizedBox( height: 20.0 ),
                  _preguntasLabel(contexto), 
                  SizedBox( height: 20.0 ),
                  Expanded(child: _listaDePreguntasFrecuentes(contexto)),     
            ],
          );

   }
```

y aqui esta mi ultimo elemento de la columna.

```
Widget _listaDePreguntasFrecuentes(BuildContext contexto){
  final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contexto).size;
  return  FutureBuilder(
           future: getQuestions(contexto),
           builder: (BuildContext contexto , AsyncSnapshot<List<Pregunta>> asyncSnapshot){

               if (!asyncSnapshot.hasData) {

                     return Center(
                        child: Text("Solicitando datos...") 
                       );

                 }
                  List<Pregunta>  listaPreguntas = asyncSnapshot.data;

                    return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length ,
                          itemBuilder: ( BuildContext contexto, int indice ) {
                                  return Card(
                                      color: Colors.brown,
                                      elevation: 10.0,
                                      child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            listaPreguntas[indice].question,
                                            style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white ),
                                            ),
                                      ),
                                  );
                          },
                      );

           }
       );
     }
```

y con todo este codigo de arriba me funciona bien el problema es cuando presiono el TextField 
 para escribir y cuando se abre el teclado me sale el error de desbordado.
 abajo pongo la imagen.
  [image: Este es el error de desbordado que me sale]

LO QUE INTENTE:
 lo primero que hice fue cambiar mi columna por un ListView con sus childrens pero me da el siguiente error y en la pantalla al final no me muestra nada mas que el fondo y el appBar.

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart': Failed 
assertion: line 1312 pos 14: '_childElements.containsKey(index)': is not true.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 
'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' 
was called on null.
```

flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on 
    null.

Muchas gracias amigos , espero me puedan ayudar gracias.
 si hay algo mas que deba incluir en la pregunta con mucho gusto.

EDITADO: 
AQUI ESTAN LOS DEMAS WIDGETS:

```
Widget _contactaMe(BuildContext contexto){
ContactProvider proveedorContacto = new ContactProvider();
final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contexto).size;
String mensajeMostrar = "";
  return   FutureBuilder(
                  future: proveedorContacto.obTainContacts(),
                  builder: (BuildContext contexto , AsyncSnapshot 
    asyncSnapshot){
                      Contacto contactoRecibido = asyncSnapshot.data;
                      if(asyncSnapshot.hasData){

                          if(!contactoRecibido.status){
                              mensajeMostrar = contactoRecibido.email;
                          }else {
                              mensajeMostrar = "Contactanos a traves 
  de ${contactoRecibido.email} o usando el formulario de consultas :";   
                          }
                           return Container( 
                          child: Text(mensajeMostrar, style: 
  TextStyle( fontSize: tamanoPhone.width * 0.04 , color: Colors.white, 
   ), 
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
             20.0  ),
                      );
                    } else {
                         return Container(
                           child: Center(
                             child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              valueColor: new 
      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.brown),
                             ),
                           ),
                         );
                    }  
                  },
              );
  }
```

EL TEXFIELD:

```
  Widget _textField(BuildContext contexto){
    final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contexto).size;
      return Container(  
            height: tamanoPhone.height * 0.30,  
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 20.0 ), 
            width: double.infinity,
           // color: Colors.red,
            child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                    _elTextFieldEnSi(contexto),
                    _elBotonEnSi(contexto),
                ],
            ),
      );    
  }
```

Y ESTE ES PREGUNTAS LABEL:

```
 Widget _preguntasLabel(BuildContext contexto){
    final tamanoPhone = MediaQuery.of(contexto).size;
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all( Radius.circular(10.0) ),
            color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Text("PREGUNTAS Y RESPUESTAS FRECUENTES", style: 
    TextStyle( fontSize: tamanoPhone.width * 0.04 , color: 
  Colors.white, )),
    );
```

}

MODIFICADO AQUI ANADO EL TEXTFIELDEN SI Y EL BOTON EN SI.

EN TEXTFIELD EN SI:

```
   Widget _elTextFieldEnSi(BuildContext contexto){

      return TextField(  
             style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white ), 
             maxLines: 10, 
             onChanged: (value){
                this.blocGeneral.addDataToStreamMensaje(value);
             },
             decoration: InputDecoration(    
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(3, 3, 3, 0.5),
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(  
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(20.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                  enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: 
       Colors.white, width: 0.5),
                        ),  
                  hintText: "Escriba su mensaje...",
                  hintStyle: TextStyle( color: Colors.white )
              ),  
        );

  }
```

EL BOTON EN SI:

```
 Widget _elBotonEnSi(BuildContext contexto){

  return StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: this.blocGeneral.mensajeStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: MaterialButton(
                  elevation: 10.0,
                  minWidth: 200.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                      String ultimoValor = snapshot.data;
                      if(ultimoValor.length == 0){
                            final snackBar = SnackBar(content: 
           Text("Porfavor ingresa un mensaje para"));

           Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      }else {

                       //enviar el  mensaje
                      }
                  },
                  color: Colors.brown,
                  child: Text("Enviar Mensaje", style: 
                 TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
      );
    }
  );
```

}

Comment: hmm es dificil replicar si no tenemos los demás widgets que usas que podrían ser los causantes como   _contactaMe(contexto),
                  _textField(contexto),
                  _preguntasLabel(contexto),

Comment: hola amigo, si ya lo hice, gracias.

Comment: en que parte del código está ese botón 'Enviar Mensaje' ?

Comment: YA LO AGREGUE LO DEL BOTON Y EL TEXFIELD.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi amigo, funciono era eso. gracias.

Comment: dale, no hay problema, no te olvides de suscribirte al canal : https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide

Comment: claro me suscribo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, identifiqué el error cuando pusiste el código completo, el problema es que el método `_textField` está creando un contenedor con un tamaño fijo basado en un porcentaje.

El `Column` principal en `_demasElementos` no es scroleable por lo que te salta el problema de overflow, para solucionar tienes que hacer estos cambios.

- Agrega `SingleChildScrollView` sobre ese `Column` dentro de `_demasElementos` y quita el `Expanded` de la lista (ya que no funciona Scroll + Expanded).

```dart
  Widget _demasElementos(BuildContext contexto) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          _contactaMe(contexto),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          _textField(contexto),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          _preguntasLabel(contexto),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          _listaDePreguntasFrecuentes(contexto),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

- Sobre la lista dentro de `_listaDePreguntasFrecuentes` , agrega la propiedad `shrinkWrap` al `ListView` y ponlo en `true`.

```dart
return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: asyncSnapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext contexto, int indice) {
              return Card(
                color: Colors.brown,
                elevation: 10.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    listaPreguntas[indice].question,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
```